# Referencing from an inner class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, keylistener, miglayout

I have the following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import Sorts.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class SortsGui
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Sorts");

    JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();

    //first panel components
    public int nextTextBox = 20;
    JTextField[] allField = new JTextField [25];
    //end first panel

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 800, 800);
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createSortTestPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(sortPanel);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createSortTestPanel()
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("" , "[grow]");
        sortPanel.setLayout(layout);

        refreshScreen();
    }

    public void refreshScreen()
    {
        sortPanel.removeAll();

        for(int i = 0; i<nextTextBox;i++)
        {
            int fix = i+1;
            allField[i] = new JTextField("");
            sortPanel.add(allField[i],"growx");
            allField[i].addKeyListener(new KeyListener ()
            {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                {

                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                {

                }

                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    char c = e.getKeyChar();
                    if(Character.isDigit(c))
                    {

                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        e.consume();
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        int parseTest = Integer.parseInt(allField[i].getText());
                    }

                    catch(Exception exc)
                    {
                        allField[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SortsGui sG = new SortsGui();
        sG.runGUI();
    }
}
```

My aim here is to create an array of JTextFields which have a keylistener on. This keylistener should prevent anything other than numbers being entered in the JTextField. It should also change the color of the JTextField's background if the number entered is not an int. For example 2147483647554.
However when I compile this I get the error

[image: Inner class error]

So how do I make this so that it is either final or effectively final on all the JTextFields?

Comment: *"My aim here is to create an array of JTextFields which have a keylistener on. This keylistener should prevent anything other than numbers being entered in the JTextField"* - Then use a `DocumentFilter` instead

Comment: *"It should also change the color of the JTextField's background if the number entered is not an int" - Then use a `InputVerifier`

Comment: you can fix the error by adding a variable final int index = i; inside your loop and referencing it instead of i

Comment: You could also use `e.getSource()` instead of directly using `allField[i]`. This way you can reuse the same listener object for all the JTextFields as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My aim here is to create an array of JTextFields which have a keylistener on. This keylistener should prevent anything other than numbers being entered in the JTextField

The short answer to this is, don't use `KeyListener`, it won't capture the use cases of the user pasting text into the field or if the field is updated programmatically

Instead you want to use a `DocumentFilter`, for example

```
public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text.length());
        for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(index))) {
                buffer.append(text.charAt(index));
            }
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
        ValidationListener listener = getValidationListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (length > 0) {
            fb.remove(offset, length);
        }
        insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}
```

See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more details and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more examples

> It should also change the color of the JTextField's background if the number entered is not an int

You can do post validation using a `InputVerifier`, but that might not meet your needs.

This creates a problem.  The `DocumentFilter`, shouldn't care about the field it's applied to, but since, it's doing the validation, it will know when something has gone wrong, so we need some way for the filter to provide notification when the validation fails...

First, we need some callback which tells us when validation has failed or passed...

```
public interface ValidationListener {

    public void validationFailed();

    public void validationPassed();
}
```

Then we need to update the filter to raise those notifications based on it's rules...

```
public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private ValidationListener validationListener;

    public void setValidationListener(ValidationListener validationListener) {
        this.validationListener = validationListener;
    }

    public ValidationListener getValidationListener() {
        return validationListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        boolean validationFailed = false;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text.length());
        for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(index))) {
                buffer.append(text.charAt(index));
            } else {
                validationFailed = true;
            }
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
        ValidationListener listener = getValidationListener();
        if (listener != null) {
            if (validationFailed) {
                listener.validationFailed();
            } else {
                listener.validationPassed();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (length > 0) {
            fb.remove(offset, length);
        }
        insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}
```

Then we need to define our implementation of the `ValidationListener` to perform the actions we need...

```
public class DefaultValidationHandler implements ValidationListener {

    private JTextField field;

    public DefaultValidationHandler(JTextField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public JTextField getField() {
        return field;
    }

    @Override
    public void validationFailed() {
        getField().setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void validationPassed() {
        getField().setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
    }

}
```

Here, the listener maintains a reference to the field which we want to control

Then we bind it altogether...

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
DefaultValidationHandler handler = new DefaultValidationHandler(field);
IntFilter filter = new IntFilter();
filter.setValidationListener(handler);
((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
```

[image: Filter]

This is all a bit crude, but it gets the basic idea across.

Some improvements might include passing the reference of the `DocumentFilter` back via the methods of the `ValidationListener`, you could then use this to lookup the field which triggered the event and update it, reducing the number of handlers you might need to create, for example.

For example

## Updated ValidationListener

```
public interface ValidationListener {

    public void validationFailed(DocumentFilter filter);

    public void validationPassed(DocumentFilter filter);
}
```

## Updated IntFilter

```
public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private ValidationListener validationListener;

    public void setValidationListener(ValidationListener validationListener) {
        this.validationListener = validationListener;
    }

    public ValidationListener getValidationListener() {
        return validationListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        boolean validationFailed = false;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text.length());
        for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(index))) {
                buffer.append(text.charAt(index));
            } else {
                validationFailed = true;
            }
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
        ValidationListener listener = getValidationListener();
        if (listener != null) {
            if (validationFailed) {
                listener.validationFailed(this);
            } else {
                listener.validationPassed(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (length > 0) {
            fb.remove(offset, length);
        }
        insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}
```

## Example implementation...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Map<DocumentFilter, JTextField> fields;

    public TestPane() {

        fields = new HashMap<>(25);
        ValidationListener listener = new ValidationListener() {

            @Override
            public void validationFailed(DocumentFilter filter) {
                JTextField field = fields.get(filter);
                if (field != null) {
                    field.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void validationPassed(DocumentFilter filter) {
                JTextField field = fields.get(filter);
                if (field != null) {
                    field.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
                }
            }
        };

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            IntFilter filter = new IntFilter();
            filter.setValidationListener(listener);
            ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
            fields.put(filter, field);
            add(field, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How would I tell it to update if the backspace key is pressed. Ie. In this example if someclicks a letter, the background of the selected text box turns red. So when they clicked the backspace key it sets the same JTextfield background back to normal?

Comment: Essentially you won't know, because honestly, you don't need to.  It's the same thing if some one selected a section of text and cut it.  The `DocumentFilter` will know when text is removed, and that's all it cares about.  A back-space character isn't an illegal character in this context, as it doesn't produce new text in the field (it removes it obviously).  You could use an `InputVerifier` to reset the background of the field when the field loses focus, verifying the content of the field

Comment: Is there a way to know when text is removed in general by any method within the DocumentFilter?

Comment: I was thinking, because of the way the example works, you can't actually enter invalid values, there's simply no way you can, instead of turning the field red permanently, you could set it red, then using a Swing Timer, reset it back to normal after a small delay

Comment: And what does the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) tell you ;) ? But from what I'm guessing, you're chasing the wrong course of action, because if the filter detects an invalid character, nothing is added to the underlying docuemnt, so pressing backspace will simple remove the last valid character

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issue that's why getting this error:

```
for(int i = 0; i<nextTextBox;i++) //you are declaring i here
```

using  inside `KeyListener` , This is prohibited. Because `local` `non-final` variable cant be accessed from inner class to access it must be final. In your case I don't think it is possible to make `i` final

So, one quick fix is declare i in the class scope with the `JFrame` and `JPanel`

```
JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Sorts");

JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();
int i;
```

then use it any where

```
 for(i = 0; i<nextTextBox;i++)
```

Comment: *"This is prohibited"* not really...troublesome for sure.  I'd suggest a better fix, but the whole approach is just, well, garbage

Comment: Isn't there a problem that all the fields will always reference the last textfield when the loop is done since they all look to the same `i` reference instead of what value it had at the moment it was instantiated? I'd suggest you make a copy of the variable in the inner class scope by `JTextField myfield = allField[i]` in the instantiation

Comment: well by `This is prohibited` i mean accessing non-final local variable from inner class in prohibited by the compiler. If i am still wrong please en light me a little. And i know its  sort of garbage :( i just wanted to keep OP code unchanged and fix the current bug.   @MadProgrammer

Comment: yeh its a possible scenario but in this code OP didn't use `i` anywhere except inside the loop. @MichaelDibbets

Comment: *"fix the current bug"* - Maybe it would be nice to not waste the poor OP's time when they are working in the wrong direction or against the API, especially when an API exists to achieve the results they want (IMHO).  Beside, they should be using `KeyEvent#getSource` and not bothering with the `i` at all, but that won't help them solve the larger problem that they are/going to be facing