# Contact number validation

Tags: java, swing, validation

I want to validate the contact no Text Field for checking if it contains digit.
I have written following function for KeyTyped but it is not working can anybody provide an alternative.Thanks in advance.

Code:-

```
private void tnoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{
    char c=evt.getKeyChar();
    System.out.println("hi");
    if(!(Character.isDigit(c)||(c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)||(c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
    {
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

Comment: What means `it is not working`?

Comment: [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908040/referencing-from-an-inner-class/30908436?s=1|0.0000#30908436)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to validate the contact no Text Field for checking if it contains digit

You can do post validation on a field using a `InputVerifer`, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details.

> I have written following function for KeyTyped but it is not working can anybody provide an alternative

You can do real time validation through the use of a `DocumentListener`, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression should do the trick:

```
char c = evt.getKeyChar();

//create a pattern that checks for digits and backspace
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\b]");  

//check if your character as a string matches the pattern
Matcher m = p.match("" + c);
boolean b = m.matches();

//I don't know if there is a regex equivilent for delete
if(!(b || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) )  {
    evt.consume();
}
```